# Customer Login Page & Forgot password page are not working

Tags: login, registration, magento2.4, customer-login

I have created a website called cravestore.in in magento2.4. I have registered myself by using Signup page, all works good, but when I tried to login with my correct credentials the customer login page just refreshes instead of completing the login process. Also, when I tried to reset the password the forgot password email is not coming on my registered mail id. Please fix these issues.

Comment: Check your cookie settings

Comment: How to check and what to do please elaborate more

Comment: Please check any error log is there or any exception is thrown or not or enable error display in app/bootstrap.php

Answer (score 0):

It seems like referrer key is not working correctly in your Magento instance. This is a feature provided by Magento. It is used to redirect a user back to the page where he tried to login to resume his navigation. For example, if a user is on a category page and clicks on login link, it will add category page as referrer in URL and will redirect the user back to the same category page after successful login. I can successfully logged in to your Magento instance without the referrer key.

While you are still debugging it and you want to make the login form work in the same time, you can disabe the referrer key feature in configuration in admin panel.

**Stores > Configurations > Customers > Customer Configuration > Login Options**

Set `Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging` in to `Yes` and you will not see referrer in the URL anymore. But this will always redirect a user to customer dashboard after login.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some setting changes in Configuration->Customers. This resolves me the issue. Thanks for your answer Rendy. I will follow your answer. If I have any problem in future.

Comment: Please share the setting changes that made your problem solved, it could be helpful others

Comment: Yes sure. sharing.